# Trigger a modal window from checkbox change event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a checkbox that currently opens a popup window on an external site allowing the user to configure options for engraving.

The script for this is:

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {
    var item = $(this);
    if (item.is(":checked")) {
      window.open('http://vrpanels.com/app#/designer/<?php echo $sku; ?>', 'Title', 'width=800,height=1200');
    }
  });
});
```

Whilst this works, it doesn't look particularly good so I want to have it in a responsive modal window.

I installed a responsive modal script and can get the function to work from a simple test link like:

```
<a href="http://vrpanels.com/app#/designer/<?php echo $sku; ?>" data-modal-title="ImageProcessor">Launch external overlay</a>
```

I'm struggling to get this to work in place of the original

```
window.open('http://vrpanels.com/app#/designer/<?php echo $sku; ?>','Title','width=800,height=1200');
```

I'm assuming I somehow need to have

```
 data-modal-title="ImageProcessor"
```

inside the window.open command

Comment: jquery ui `dialog` is your friend

Comment: use an iframe maybe?